# Django - data as in firebase but on my server

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

we have prototype of frontend write with firebase. Our company security policy do not allow us to use firebase, moust of our tools are written in python/django, so we want to write in django backend which do not work on tables but on dictionary structure. Could you recomend me same framework which allow me to in easy and fast way write samething similar do firebase.